# Jmeter Not sending Header named Cookie

Tags: jmeter

My Api call has a header named Cookie. But while sending header named Cookie, jmeter is not sending the header. The header manager works for anything other than named Cookie or cookie.

Comment: Have you tried cookie manager element?

Comment: My api needs a cookie as well as a header named cookie.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today. The problem was that I tried to POST instead of GET.

Fixing this, JMeter handled the request correctly. And this was the case, although the cookie was shown under "Cookie Data".

Answer (score 0):

I am considering that you are using HTTP header Manager for the same, Did u tried with putting the single quotes around your header name...!!

Comment: Tried putting quotes but Jmeter sent the quotes as well so did not work.

Comment: Is it possible if you can share your project/script..would like to mimic it and then see what else can be done, my apology I do not have any api which accepts cookie as an header..!!

Comment: I think you can try any dummy api and add a header named 'Cookie' in header manager. The api may not work but  in result tree you can see if it gets passed or not. Let me know if you still need the jmx

Answer (score 0):

Cookie is part of the  [Standard HTTP request fields](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) ,so it's reserved word.

To add cookie(s) in JMeter use  [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)

Comment: My request uses the header named Cookie so need to pass it using header manager

Comment: See http://jmeter.apache.org/images/screenshots/http-config/http-cookie-manager.png

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem using [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4)

1. [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) configuration

   [image: JMeter HTTP Header Manager]
2. Request in the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

   [image: JMeter Add Header]

So make sure that you:

- Use [latest JMeter version](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version)
- Add a HTTP Header Manager
- Add a Header in the HTTP Header Manager
- Put your HTTP Request Sampler(s) into the HTTP Header Manager [scope](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/ScopingRules)
- Check *jmeter.log* file for any suspicious entries

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. In my case, the Request Header needs a key named Cookie and value also. In your screenshot, it passes as cookie but not as a header named Cookie

Comment: Please look at the point : Cookie is not going request headers.